# A word for a study done by both experiment and simulation

Tags: word-request

I want to know there is a word that describes an investigation that is done by experiment and simulation simultaneously. Is something like **an experiment-simulation study** correct and natural?

Comment: There is no common word that gives this meaning. If you find an arcane way to do this your readers won’t know what you are talking about. Just spell it out. “We used a combination of experimentation and simulation to ...”

Comment: @jwpfox Yes, I don't want to use an arcane word. I thought that there is a common word. By the way, could you tell me what the difference is between experiment and experimentation? I looked them up in a dictionary but could not make out.

Comment: A(n) combined/integrated theoretical/simulation and experimental study

Comment: A simulation is a kind of experiment.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty That’s not true. A simulation may or may not be an experiment. Look it up.

Comment: @lee Experimentation is the process of undertaking an experiment. Like simulation is the action of simulating something (as one of its meanings).

Comment: @jwpfox If it isn't an experiment, it's otiose.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty You are simply wrong again. The simulation may be to establish the “as is” baseline before conducting experiments and measuring the change from the baseline as a result of the experiment. Or a lot of other possible purposes that would not satisfy the meaning of “experiment”. I know you are one of the royalty of this little forum but you aren’t infallible.

Comment: @jwpfox If you are establishing a baseline you are discovering something you didn't know before. That is an experiment. That it's a prelude to another sort of experiment doesn't make it not an experiment. Try to stick to the subject under discussion instead of making personal comments.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Again you are wrong. I’m stopping now.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Whether a simulation run is referred to as an "experiment" or not depends on the jargon of the specific field. For example, in condensed-matter physics, simulations are considered "theoretical" tools (even if they are based completely on empirical data). Physicists who exclusively do simulations (as I did) were considered "theorists", not "experimentalists". Experimentalists do sometimes run simulations, but those are not considered "experiments".

Comment: @CanadianYankee  I don't doubt what you say, in terms of what the usual terminology is.. I started with the anodyne observation that a simulation is a kind of experiment. I don't see how one can simply say "that's wrong."